# Difference between class/instance attribute and class/instance variable

Tags: python, class, variables, attributes

```
class Cat:

  def __init__(self, name, color):
    self.name = name
    self.color = color
```

While trying to find an answer to my question, I think I have learnt this:

- attributes are characteristics of a class: every Cat has a color and a name.
- All methods and variables are attributes

Different people, and sites, use different names, for what I believe, is the same thing. Some use the word 'instance attribute' when they talk about `self.name = name` while others use the word 'instance variable' when they talk bout `self.name = name` - The same thing!

So what confuses me is why two different words (attribute and variable) is used to explain the same thing. What is the difference between attribute and variable?

Comment: all variables are attributes but not all attributes are variables, an attribute would be anything that you access through the instance or class (e.g., `self.name` or `Cat.some_class_attribute`), a variable is simply a variable but in case of it being related to a class or instance it could be considered a class or instance variable

Comment: Why do people use inconsistent, imprecise and inaccurate terminology _for anything_? This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: The only terminology you should care about is the one that is recognized by the [Python lexical analyzier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). Note that those names like *variable*,*constants* or simliar can be called **identifier** and are just differently refered to point out a specific case. How yourself call a identifier won't have any effect on how they will be interpreted.